# How to Cut Hex Before a Pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed, hex, cut

```
DEA98C18 C56E53AB 46E715A9 03C8AC9E 01E6A760 3B8C3E77 5F60DF29 719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA D8FED2FE B4C8C527 F0CD50B1 2AA200DD 0F07E4B1 54C73A4B 5C0AB6FF 54F3A4CE 72272FE6 111EECFD 719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA
```

I Have a very long HEX File like in the above pattern now i need to cut every 7 HEX Before the pattern "719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA"

So the output will look like

```
719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA D8FED2FE B4C8C527 F0CD50B1 719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA
```

I don't know how to ask this question in a proper way my native language is not english

Answer (score 5):

The `sed` command

```
sed -r 's/([0-9A-F]{8} ){7}(719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA)/\2/g' hex_file
```

finds

- seven `{7}` repetitions of

  - eight `{8}` repetitions of hexadecimal characters `[0-9A-F]`
  - followed by a space
- followed by the pattern `719F0E71 7BA656EE 8500D7FA`

... and then replaces that with the second matched group `\2`, which is the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: it works for this sample input only. But op has a long hex file.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It does exactly what OP asked ... what input doesn't it work on?

Comment: oh, i forget that. And +1 from me.